# doctrine join with condition

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have 3 tables : exam, field and data.

The relations are :

exam manyToMany field ; field oneToMany data ; exam oneToMany data

I need to specify the field_id AND the exam_id to get the needed data
In SQL I do this :

```
SELECT * FROM exam
LEFT JOIN field ON exam.id = field.exam_id
LEFT JOIN data ON field.id = data.field_id AND (data.exam = exam.id)
```

That works

In Doctrine :

```
$this->_em->getRepository('FwFollowBundle:Exam')
        ->createQueryBuilder('exam')
->leftJoin('exam.field', 'field')
->leftJoin('field.data', 'data', 'WITH', 'data.exam = exam')
->select ('exam', 'field', 'data')
```

The result is not filtered by the 'WITH' condition.

I want to return all exams with their fields and, if they have, their data

I someone know why. Thx

***EDIT 1 :*** 
I made some dump to try to found the problem.
In my project, I have a step between exam and field. 
I do this

```
$this->_em->getRepository('FwFollowBundle:Exam')
->createQueryBuilder('exam')
->leftJoin('exam.score', 'score')
->leftJoin('score.fields', 'field')
->leftJoin('field.data', 'data', 'WITH', 'data.exam = exam')
->select ('exam', 'score', 'field', 'data')
```

For 2 exams I have the same scores, so the same fields. I only have differences with data.
It's the same instance of Field entity for 2 exams. That's the reason I do not have the wanted data.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
return $this->_em->getRepository('FwFollowBundle:Exam')
    ->createQueryBuilder('exam')
    ->leftJoin('exam.field', 'field')
    ->leftJoin('field.data', 'data')
    ->where('data.exam = :exam')
    ->setParameter('exam', 'exam.id')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult()
;
```

Comment: Thx, but with your query I have nothing in return

Comment: My answer was short sorry.With your query, only exam with data were return. I need to return all exams, with their fields and, if exist, the data

Answer (score 0):

You need to select the entities you want to be hydrated, otherwise when you call $exam->getField()->getData() doctrine will lazy load everything with no criteria.

I'd re-write your query something like:

```
$exam = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder()
->select('exam', 'field', 'data')
->from('FwFollowBundle:Exam', 'exam')
->leftJoin('exam.field', 'field')
->leftJoin('field.data', 'data', 'WITH', 'data.exam = exam')
->getQuery()
->getResult();
```

Comment: My query was not complet, I have the select condition to hydrate the relation.